# Project bootstrap ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I've got the theme "darkly" at bootswatch, but whenever I run the application I get the same theme as the starter.

If I make any change on my project, the theme changes to "darkly" but if I press F5 I get the starter one again.

[image]

I found the problem but couldn't solve it. When running the application it's getting another bootstrap.min.css instead of mine. I didn't find where is the bootstrap.min.css the application is running but if I do you'll get noticed!

Here is the code:
https://github.com/GlennMateus/MVC-test

All css and js files are into aula_1/aula_1.

Comment: Have you pointed your BundleConfig.cs to the correct version of "~/css/bootstrap.min.css"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked your files and **could** be the bundles.
The default bundles can come with css files from web.
After debugging check which files are being used.

Look at App_Start > BundleConfig and edit the files from there.

The renderers are on Views>Shared>_Layout.cshtml. You can, optionaly, remove the `@Styles.Render` and make them manually.

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Or drag and drop you files from solution window.

Try to remove the cache if not done already. (Ctrl+F5)

About bundling:
[Bundling](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: The bootstrap-theme.min.css needs referencing in the config. I wouldn't add the links manually as that defeats the object of using templates in the first place.

Comment: You might want to add App_Start as the default edit location of the BundleConfig to your answer.

Comment: Should have said about the bundleconfig from beggining. My actual projects are on mvc4 so some new stuff I dont really know or remember about. TY

Comment: Hey guys !! I really really appreciate your help!
Yesterday's night I've discovered that the problem is just Chrome's cache...
Once I've tried to run the application with Firefox it was fixed xD

Tkank y'all for helping